# Understanding statistical hist and quantitle Plots and how to drop unreliable data

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn, statsmodels

I downloaded weather data and performed some statistical checks. Basically checking if data is okay to use. Does it satisfy normal distribution? or there completely straight lines? or just constant values due to some error. I want to find and drop such data.

My code:

```
from meteostat import Point, Hourly
import statsmodels.api as sm
import pylab

## Geographical location details
lati = 39.758949
long = -84.191605
elev = 225

## get the data
start_date = datetime.strptime(df.index.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')[0], '%Y-%m-%d')
end_date = datetime.strptime(df.index.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')[-1], '%Y-%m-%d')
location = Point(lati, long, elev)
hourly_data = Hourly(location, start_date, end_date)
hourly_data = hourly_data.fetch()

# Basic filtering functions
def drop_low_count_numeric_columns(df, count_limit = 50):
    """
    df: dataframe
    count_limit : drop column(s) if it has less than count_limit (%) numeric data.
    """
    # total length or count
    tot_cnt = len(df)
    #
    cols_cnt = df.count(numeric_only=True)
    cols_cnt = cols_cnt[cols_cnt > len(df)*(count_limit/100)].index
    return df[cols_cnt]

hourly_data = drop_low_count_numeric_columns(hourly_data)
# plot statistical normal distribution and quantile plots
fig,ax = plt.subplots(nrows=len(hourly_data.columns), ncols=2, figsize=(10,16))
#                       ,squeeze=False,
#                       height_ratios=[0.4]*len(hourly_data.columns))
for col in hourly_data.columns:    
# col = 'pres'
    # Seaborn histplot with kernel distribution estimate line (applicable to univariate data)
    sns.histplot(hourly_data[col], kde=True,ax=ax[hourly_data.columns.tolist().index(col),0])
    # quantile-quantile plot
    sm.qqplot(hourly_data[col], line='s',ax=ax[hourly_data.columns.tolist().index(col),1])
pylab.show()
# plt.subplots_adjust(left=0.1,
#                     bottom=0.1,
#                     right=0.9,
#                     top=0.9,hspace=1, wspace=1)
fig.tight_layout(pad=5.0)
plt.show()
```

[image]

My questions:

1. what and how do I have to understand the above statistical plots? what do they signify? For instance, 4th sub-left-plot seems to have just one bin. Indicating that it has only one repeating value. No other values. I would like to identify such columns logically or through some score and drop them.
2. I have complete knowledge what the histogram with x-axis denoting values and y-axis denoting frequency. But, I have zero knowledge of what is on the x-axis and y-axis in the qq plot. What is theoretical and sample quantile here?
3. I did my best (as you can see from the commented lines in my code) to adjust subplot height so I want to see the each x-axis lablel. The label usually denotes the column name. All my efforts were in vain.

Comment: This seems to be a math/statistics question, not a programming question, i.e. I don't think this is a question for stack overflow.

Comment: @jared Looks like my 3Q was lost in the list. I appreciate if you could help me with it.

Comment: You have pylab imported, but call matplotlib, which isn't imported. Assuming you are using matplotlib, have you tried `fig.tight_layout()`?

Comment: @jared it is there in my code above.

Comment: Sorry, I missed that.